# why do network Switches uses ASIC chip instead of programming like routers

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, cisco-router

I was studying programming when I learned that switches function on ASIC chips but why do they do that, cant they switch to programming like router does

Comment: Switches are not all built the same. Some switches use ASIC chips some use other chips.

Comment: To add to @Ramhound's comment, in addition there is a big cost difference too. Programming architecture for a switch require more expensive components and people's time to program the chips and maintain that programming. As a result, switches that have these are more expensive. Another note is that routers may still use switches with ASIC chips and only have limited programming for the router part, again for the same reason.

Comment: Why is this question closed as opinion based? @LPChip comment seems to be a rather factual answer.

Comment: @lx07 I'd say, this question is borderline.

Comment: Why a manufacturer chooses one method over another is not a problem with computer hardware or software, it is a problem with economics and reliability and other factors.